# Logical error with nested if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, nested

I am trying to create a program that presents the top 5 places in a race. The code compiles, but when you run it there is an obvious logical error. It repeats the same finalist in all 5 places, so first place gets placed in first, second, third, and so on...

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment0
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int numberOfLanes;
        int lane = 0;
        double first;
        double second;
        double third;
        double fourth;
        double fifth;
        double [] time = null;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println ("How many lanes hold competitors?");
        numberOfLanes = keyboard.nextInt();

        time = new double [numberOfLanes];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLanes; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter time for lane " + i);
            time [i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

         first = time[0];

         for (int i = 0; i < time.length; i++)
         {
             if ( time[i] < first)
                {
                    first = time[i];
                    lane = i;
                }
         }

         System.out.println("First place = Lane " + lane + ". Time = " + first + " seconds.");

         second = time[0];

         for (int i = 0; i < time.length; i++)
         {
             if (time [i] > first)
                if (time [i] < second)
                {
                     second = time[i];
                     lane = i;
                } 
         }

         System.out.println("Second place = Lane " + lane + ". Time = " + second + " seconds.");

         third = time[0];

         for (int i = 0; i < time.length; i++)
         {
             if (time[i] > second)
                if (time[i] < third)
                {
                    third = time[i];
                    lane = i;
                }

         }

         System.out.println("Third place = Lane " + lane + ". Time = " + third + " seconds.");

         fourth = time[0];

         for (int i = 0; i < time.length; i++)
         {
             if (time[i] > third)
                if (time[i] < fourth)
                            {    
                              fourth = time[i];
                              lane = i;
                            }
         }


         System.out.println("Fourth place = Lane " + lane + ". Time = " + fourth + " seconds.");

         fifth = time[0];

         for (int i = 0; i < time.length; i++)
         {
           if (time [i] > fourth)
            if (time[i] < fifth)
              {
                fifth = time[i];
                lane = i;
              }
         }


         System.out.println("Fifth place = Lane " + lane + ". Time = " + fifth + " seconds.");
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
How many lanes hold competitors?
5
Enter time for lane 0
9.72
Enter time for lane 1
9.8
Enter time for lane 2
9.82
Enter time for lane 3
9.86
Enter time for lane 4
9.9


First place = Lane 0. Time = 9.72 seconds.
Second place = Lane 0. Time = 9.72 seconds.
Third place = Lane 0. Time = 9.72 seconds.
Fourth place = Lane 0. Time = 9.72 seconds.
Fifth place = Lane 0. Time = 9.72 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is not a good way of approaching the problem. However, if we stick with this method, the solution is to initialise `second`, `third`, `fourth` and `fifth` like this:

```
second = Double.MAX_VALUE;
```

And so on for 3rd to 5th. You will also need to put this as the head of your code:

```
import java.lang.Double;
```

Note however that even with the fix above, if two lanes have identical times the second lane will be skipped and the last lane will have a time of `MAX_VALUE`, so you will need to rewrite the code completely to use arrays and sort them.

Answer (score 1):

You set `second = time[0];`, `third = time[0]`, etc. prior to each loop so in each `for` loop the if statement conditions are never true, hence the variables `second`, `third`, etc. never change from `time[0]` and `lane` never change from `0`.

You should instead initialize them with `Double.MAX_VALUE`. Specifically, at declaration, use the following code:

```
    int numberOfLanes;
    int lane = 0;
    double first = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double second = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double third = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double fourth = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double fifth = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double [] time = null;
```

and remove all `second = time[0];`, `third = time[0]`, and so on.

Comment: Should I initiate the variable to a different element in the array? I know in order for the code to compile with the variable it has to be initialized to some value.

Comment: Initialize every variable to `Double.MAX_VALUE` and you should be good to go. I'll update my post with specific code.

Answer (score 0):

Your initializations are weird, instead of setting `first = time[0]` and such, just initialize them to infinity and remove the individual assignment lines.

```
double first = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
double second = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
double third = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
double fourth = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
double fifth = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
first = time[0];
```

until

```
fifth = time[0];
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer at all?

Answer (score 0):

change `second = time[0];`  to `second = time[1];`

`third = time[0];` to `third = time[2];`

`fourth = time[0];` to `fourth = time[3];`

`fifth = time[0];` to `fifth = time[4];`

Comment: That only works with this particular data set that is already in order.

Comment: I tried this solution with a different data set and it worked. That this code is not the best method to approach the issue from; so I will continue to work with this program on my own and continue researching it. If anyone has any suggestions on reputable articles or websites for reviewing it all I would appreciate any help.

Comment: @KenY-N: I am aware that this only works for this particular data set. I just pointed the logical error.

Answer (score 0):

You assign `second` and all further ranks unconditionally before the loop that compares times. So if the fastest time is placed as element `[0]` you will get the observed behavior. You should read about `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

how about this :

```
    String[] data = new String[]{"First","Second","Third", "Forth", "Fifth"};
    int num[] = new int[]{0,1,2,3,4};
    //now we sort the array(time) and we note the index
    for(int a=0;a<numberOfLanes;a++){
        for(int b=a+1;b<numberOfLanes;b++){
            if(time[a]>time[b]){
                int temp=time[a];
                time[a] = time[b];
                time[b] = temp;

                temp = num[a];
                num[a] = num[b];
                num[b] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    //--
    //print the output
    for(int a=0;a<numberOfLanes;a++){
        System.out.println(data[a]+" place = Lane "+num[a]+". Time = "+time[a]+" seconds.");
    }
    //-- done
```